# Corona error: attempt to call global "startButtonListeners" <a nil value>

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm making a main menu scene in corona, however I've come across an error and its driving me crazy.

The compiler makes it confusing for me to understand what it is but I can point out 2 problems from it:

- attempt to call global "startButtonListeners"
- [C] in function "startButtonListeners"

Here is the section of code:

```
 function scene:enterScene(event)
    local group = self.view 
    startButtonListeners('add')

    function startButtonListeners(action)
      if(action == 'add') then  
         aboutBtn:addEventListener('tap', showCredits)
         startBtn:addEventListener('tap', startBtn)
      end 

      local function onSceneTouch( self, event )
        if event.phase == "began" then
        storyboard.gotoScene( "scene1", fade, 500 )
        return true
      end
    end 
end
```

Comment: You should define your function BEFORE using it.

Comment: Your function `onSceneTouch` is useless as it is visible only inside `startButtonListeners` and not used there.

Comment: sorry I'm still learning...would it be possible if you could edit the code to show me what it should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the location of your function `startButtonListeners` to the end; after your function definition is complete:

```
scene:enterScene(event)
    local group = self.view 

    function startButtonListeners(action)
      if(action == 'add') then  
         aboutBtn:addEventListener('tap', showCredits)
         startBtn:addEventListener('tap', startBtn)
      end 

      local function onSceneTouch( self, event )
        if event.phase == "began" then
        storyboard.gotoScene( "scene1", fade, 500 )
        return true
      end
    end 
    startButtonListeners('add')
end
```