# attempt to call method 'addEventListeners' (a nil value)

Tags: button, lua, coronasdk

--THIS IS THE ERROR

### --File: menu.lua

```
Line: 131
--Attempt to call method 'addEventListeners' (a nil value)
--stack traceback:
--  menu.lua:131: in function 'startButtonListeners'
--  menu.lua:179: in function <menu.lua:32> --"startButtonListeners('add')"--
--  ?: in function 'dispatchEvent'
--  ?: in function 'gotoScene'
```

-- I can't understand where I must put "`startButtonListeners('add')`"

```
local sceneGroup = self.view

background = display.newImageRect( "img/bg.png", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
background.anchorX = 0
background.anchorY = 0
background.x, background.y = 0, 0   

titleLogo = display.newImageRect( "img/title.png", 356, 132 )
titleLogo.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
titleLogo.y = 150



-- button2
tasto2 = display.newImage('img/tasto2.png', 356,66)     
tasto2.x = display.contentWidth *0.5
tasto2.y = 300


sceneGroup:insert( background )
sceneGroup:insert( titleLogo )
sceneGroup:insert( tasto2 )


--listener "tap" 
function startButtonListeners(action)
    if (action == 'add')  then
        tasto2:addEventListeners ('tap', showInfo) --THIS IS LINE 131

    else
        tasto2:removeEventListeners ('tap', showInfo)

    end
end



function showInfo:tap(e)
        tasto2.isVisible = false
        titleLogo.isVisible = false
        infoView = display.newImage('img/bg.jpg', display.contentWidth *0.5, display.contentHeight *0.5)

        lastY = titleLogo.y

        transition.to(infoView, 
        {time = 400, 
        y = (display.contentHeight * 0.5) , 
        onComplete = function() 
        infoView:addEventListener('tap', hideInfo) end})
end


function hideInfo:tap(e) 
        transition.to(infoView, 
        {time = 300, 
        y = display.contentHeight + 25, 
        onComplete = function() 
            tasto2.isVisible = true
            titleLogo.isVisible = true`enter code here`
            infoView:removeEventListener('tap', hideInfo) 
            display.remove(infoView) infoView = nil end}) 
            transition.to(titleLogo, {time = 300, y = lastY}); 
end 
startButtonListeners('add')
```

Comment: The language is unfamiliar to me, but generally with listeners you want to add them to your buttons right after you create them and pass them who is listening to them. If you pass an empty value, it won't have anything to notify when the button is clicked. Look up Observer Pattern for more information on how listeners work.

Comment: I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760576/corona-error-attempt-to-call-global-startbuttonlisteners-a-nil-value
he puts "startButtonListeners('add')" at the end, before to close the scene.
The code is very similar: I must activate listeners for Button "tasto2", define my function and after use it.
Nothing to do

Comment: @Steve: The error message indicates that there is no method called `addEventListeners` in the `tasto2` object. The code you linked to in your comment uses `addEventListener` (without the plural s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried addEventListener? I don't think addEventListeners is a valid function ...

Answer (score 0):

May be Corona Failed to load image from path and returned nil?

Comment: No, it isn't. To be sure, I've changed the image of infoView 'img / bg.jpg' to 'img /  tasto2.png'.
It isn't the problem.
Thank you!